# Disable sorting fields value alphabetically

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using Spring Boot (v2.1.3 RELEASE) and SpringDoc. I already went through https://springdoc.org/springdoc-properties.html and https://springdoc.org/, but it looks like SpringDoc is automatically sorting the parameters alphabetically. How can we prevent this?

```java
@Operation(summary = "Find Students")
@Parameter(in=ParameterIn.QUERY, name="page", description="Results page you want to retrieve (0..N)", schema=@Schema(defaultValue = 0))
@Parameter(in=ParameterIn.QUERY, name="size", description="Number of records per page.", schema=@Schema(defaultValue =50))
@Parameter(in=ParameterIn.QUERY, name="search_type", description=AppConstants.SEARCH_TYPE, schema=@Schema(allowableValues= {"Starts", "Contains"},defaultValue = "Starts"))
@ApiCountryHeader
@GetMapping(value = "/students")
public ResponseEntity<List<Students>> findStudentss(
        @Parameter(description  = "") @RequestParam(required = false) String studentCd,
        @Parameter(description  = "") @RequestParam(required = false) String studentName,
        @Parameter(hidden=true) String search_type){

    ....
    ....
    ...
    return new ResponseEntity<>(studentts, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Why does the order matter? Query parameters are mapped by name, not index.

Comment: Order matter because in the same query Param I want to provide option partial Search by Name, Full Search or Fuzzy search. So both query parameters should be adjescent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields are not sorted alphabetically, but the order of declaration is preserved.

You can change the fields order, using the different available customizers:

- OpenApiCustomiser: To customize the OpenAPI object
- OperationCustomizer: To customize an operation based on the HandlerMethod

For example:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/persons")
    public String getPerson(String b, String a) {
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    OperationCustomizer operationCustomizer() {
        return (Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) -> {
            if ("getPerson".equals(handlerMethod.getMethod().getName())) {
                List<Parameter> parameterList = operation.getParameters();
                if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(parameterList))
                    Collections.reverse(parameterList);
            }
            return operation;
        };
    }

}
```