# How to sort parameters in Swagger 3? Open API

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

is there a way to order the parameters alphabetically in Swagger 3 (OpenAPI 3)? I already sort by controllers' names, operations and fields, but cannot find a way to sort the parameters. From the picture below, I'd like to have: from, jgabsid, to

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.doc-expansion=none
springdoc.swagger-ui.tags-sorter=alpha
springdoc.swagger-ui.operations-sorter=alpha
springdoc.writer-with-order-by-keys=true
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `OperationCustomizer` to sort the parameters in the order that you want. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62283024/113116)

Comment: Thank you, but should the ```OperationCustomizer ``` be added to every controller?